# Returning Value From Window To Class WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, return-value

Within a method in my class I call `Login.Show()`, which is a `Login Window`. I would like the window to pass the email back to the class when the Login button is clicked, without creating a new instance of the class.

Is there any way to do this?

Currently I have

```
Login loginWindow;
public void AppStartup {
    loginWindow = new Login();
    loginWindow.Show();
    //in this instance I'd like the email to be returned here
```

Within the `Login.xaml.cs`

```
public void Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string email;
    try {
        email = InputEmail.Text;
        //ideally I would like to return email to AppStartup without
        //using new AppStartup(); , rather back in the same instance
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); 
    }
}
```

Comment: i would read up on `mvvm` & `binding` for wpf

Comment: Just add a public property to the LoginWindow class and set it in the Login_Click handler

Comment: you know, that it is tricky to use `Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);` method from WPF (or even WinForms) application?

Comment: You may want to use `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()`. Then you can access the member variable @Jon suggest after the call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could call `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()` to display the window and then access the `Text` property of the `InputEmail` control directly:

```
loginWindow = new Login();
loginWindow.ShowDialog();
string email = loginWindow.InputEmail.Text;
```

Unlike `Show()`,  `ShowDialog()` won't return until the window has been closed.

Or you could add a property to the `Login` window or its `DataContext`, and set this one when the button is clicked.

```
public string Email { get; set; }

public void Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Email = InputEmail.Text;
}
```

---

```
string email = loginWindow.Email;
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesnt seem to work, it doesnt wait for Login_Click so 'email' value is always nothing. Do I need to use a while loop and wait for Login click to be triggered?

Comment: You need to call `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()`. Did you really try this?

Comment: Yes, but it runs through showdialog and email =window.email instantly and so it never gives it a chance to update, as in wait for login click to occur. I almost need it to be like await login click ? Does this make sense?

Comment: No, `ShowDialog` doesn't return until `loginWindow` has been closed. And you can't click on a button after a window has been closed...

Comment: Oh...does the window need to be closed to pass the results back? If it's a login window I dont want it to close if the details they entered were incorrect

Comment: It needs to close before the method that calls ShowDialog continues to the next line...if you don't want this you could raise an event from the login window and handle this in your app class.